# Lambdas, alphas in Scalaz

Tags: scalaz

In many traits' signatures one can spot this awkwardly looking syntax:

`private trait CompositionPlus[F[_], G[_]] extends Plus[λ[α => F[G[α]]]]`

Could somebody explain to me the `λ[α => F[G[α]]]` part? Both `λ` and `α` seems undefined.

EDIT:
I see what this syntax does but I wonder how is it interpreted by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax comes from [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector). It is a compiler plugin that rewrites

```
λ[α => F[G[α]]]
```

to

```
({ type L[α] = F[G[α]] })#L
```

Comment: much thanks, do you use IntelliJ? It seems that I have kind projection enabled in editor settings, nonetheless I get syntax errors in source files. May you know why?